# Can't load texture in webgl

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

i am trying to load up a single texture on a triangle in webgl. here is my code. I get no error but 2 warnings & i am unable to find out the reason for it, The warnings are :

```
INVALID_VALUE: enableVertexAttribArray: index out of range
INVALID_VALUE: vertexAttribPointer: index out of range
```

The program should load up the given texture and display the rectangle.
i was following the tutorial from [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html). what could be the possible reasons fro it? here is [JSBIN OUTPUT](https://jsbin.com/waribayedu/edit?html,js,output)

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
document.body.appendChild(canvas)

// Create a canvas webgl context as a base to draw upon
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl')
//  Clear canvas with any color you want
gl.clearColor(0.75, 0.85, 0.8, 1.0)
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

// webgl pipeline need 2 shaders 1) vertex shader & fragment shader
// crate a vertex shader & compile it
var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, [
'attribute vec2 a_texcoord;',
'varying vec2 v_texcoord;',

'attribute vec2 position;',
 'void main() {',
   'gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);',
    'v_texcoord = a_texcoord;',
  '}'
].join('\n'))
gl.compileShader(vertexShader)

if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        console.error('ERROR compiling vertex shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
}

// create a fragment shader & compile it 
var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, [
'precision mediump float;',
'varying vec2 v_texcoord;',
'uniform sampler2D u_texture;',
 'void main() {',
   '   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);',
 '}'
].join('\n'))
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader)

if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
   console.error('ERROR compiling fragment shader!',     
   gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
}

// Create a program that will be offloaded to the GPU
var program = gl.createProgram()

// Attach vertex shader & fragment shaders to the the program
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)

// Link program
// gl.linkProgram(program)
gl.linkProgram(program);
if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.error('ERROR linking program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
}
gl.validateProgram(program);
if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
console.error('ERROR validating program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
}

// Define vertex positions as float32 array elemnets
var vertices = new Float32Array([
  -0.5, -0.5,
  0.5,  -0.5,
  0.0,   0.5
]);

// Create buffer where data will be stored
var buffer = gl.createBuffer()
// Mark the given buffer as current/active buffer
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
// Add data to the active buffer
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW)

const colors = [
    1,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,    // white
    0,  1.0,  0.3,  1.0,    // red
    0.0,  0.0,  0.8,  1.0,  // green
];

const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// Tell webgl to use the progr that we created
gl.useProgram(program)

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)

// Get location of the attribute `position` defined in our shader program
program.position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position')
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.position)
gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texcoords");

var Texbuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, Texbuffer);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// We'll supply texcoords as floats.
gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// Fill the texture with a 1x1 blue pixel.
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));

// Asynchronously load an image
var image = new Image();

image.src = "tex.jpg";
image.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Now that the image has loaded make copy it to the texture.
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
});

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length / 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled an attribute variable from your vertex shader.

```
var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texcoords");
```

It should be `"a_texcoord"` instead.

Also a tip, you can create multi line strings in JS using ``.

e.g.

```
var vertexShader = `
    precision lowp float;

    attribute aPosition;
    attribute aUV;

    varying vec2 vUV;

    void main() {
        vUV = aUV;
        gl_Position = vec4(aPosition,0.0,1.0);
    }
`;
```

Edit:

In case you can't find a solution to your problem I've created an example that should show you what you wanted to do.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
   
   script {
    display: none;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  // Self executing function
  void function() {
  
   // Turn on strict rules for JS
   "use strict";
   
   var canvasWidth = 180;
   var canvasHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var gl = null;
   
   // helper functions
   
   // Creates shader programs with vs & fs code as a single string
   function createProgram(vertexCode,fragmentCode) {
    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader,vertexCode);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentCode);
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
    
    try {
     if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw "VS: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);
     }
     
     if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw "FS: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);
     }
    } catch(log) {
     gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
     gl.deleteShader(fragmentShader);
     console.error(log);
    }
    
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    
    gl.attachShader(program,vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
    gl.deleteShader(fragmentShader);
    
    return program;
   }
   
   function createBuffer(data) {
    data = data instanceof Float32Array ? data : new Float32Array(data);
   
    var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,data,gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    return buffer;
   }
   
   // Creates a texture from an existing canvas or HTMLImage (new Image())
   // without needing width & height or with a typed array (Uint8Array) that has
   // a specified width & height
   // e.g.
   // createTexture(HTMLImageElement) will work just fine
   // createTexture(Uint8Array,width,height), remember that a texture needs four values for one pixel
   function createTexture(image,width,height) {
    var texture = gl.createTexture();
    
    // Set the active texture slot to 0
    // WebGL has ~30 texture slots, meaning you could have about 30 textures bound at once
    // Think of it as an array of 30 pointers to texture objects that you can set
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0); // Sets the current 'index'
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,texture); // binds the selected texture object to the current pointer
    
    // How to filter the texture when it needs resizing when sampled
    // (Is it going to be blurred when streched?)
    // (gl.NEAREST means no blur)
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
    
    // What to do if UV coordinates go outside the texture's size
    // gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE repeats the pixel at the texture's border.
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D,gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    
    width === undefined && height === undefined ?
     gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,image):
     gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,width,height,0,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,image);
     
    return texture;
   }
   
   var program = null;
   var buffer = null;
   var texture = null;
   
   // Program Attributes
   var aPosition = null;
   var aUV = null;
   
   // Program uniforms
   var uTexture = null;
   
   // Runs when page is finished loading
   // Treat it like the 'main' function seen in other languages
   onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || console.error("WebGL is not supported");
    
    // Create GL resources
    program = createProgram(`
     precision lowp float;
     
     attribute vec2 aPosition; // Vertex Pos
     attribute vec2 aUV; // Texture Coordinate
     
     varying vec2 vUV; // Texture coordinate to interpolate across pixels
     
     void main() {
      vUV = aUV;
      gl_Position = vec4(aPosition,0.0,1.0);
     }
    `,`
     precision lowp float;
     
     varying vec2 vUV; // Interpolated value from the vertex shader
     
     uniform sampler2D uTexture; // uniforms are values sent to the shader from JS
            // sampler2D vars are just integers that say what
            // texture index they are going to read from
     
     void main() {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture,vUV);
     }
    `);
    
    aPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"aPosition");
    aUV = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"aUV");
    
    uTexture = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"uTexture");
    
    // Vertex floats that are given to the GPU
    // It's more efficient to think of verticies as groups of
    // floats that form 1 set of attributes
    // e.g. the program I made has two attributes
    // aPosition & aUV which are two 2D vectors, four floats in total.
    // Therefore each four floats in my vertex buffer make up one vertex
    buffer = createBuffer([
     // X  Y     U   V
      0.5, 0.5, 1.0,0.0,
     -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,0.0,
      0.5,-0.5, 1.0,1.0,
      
      0.5,-0.5, 1.0,1.0,
     -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,0.0,
     -0.5,-0.5, 0.0,1.0,
    ]);
    
    // Create some noise to use as a texture
    var width = 32;
    var height = 32;
    var pixels = new Uint8Array((width * height) << 2);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
     pixels[i + 0] = (Math.random() * 255) | 0;
     pixels[i + 1] = (Math.random() * 255) | 0;
     pixels[i + 2] = (Math.random() * 255) | 0;
     pixels[i + 3] = 255;
    }
    
    texture = createTexture(pixels,width,height);
    
    // Setup GL State
    gl.useProgram(program); 
    gl.uniform1i(uTexture,0);
    
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer);
    
    // These functions tell WebGL how to interpret the vertexbuffer data
    
    // Every sixteen bytes, use the first eight (4 bytes is a float) for the 'aPosition' attribute
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(aPosition,2,gl.FLOAT,gl.FALSE,16,0);
    
    // Every sixteen bytes, use the last eight bytes for the 'aUV' attribute
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(aUV,2,gl.FLOAT,gl.FALSE,16,8);
    
    // These need to be enabled or the vertex data isn't fed indo the vertex shader
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aPosition);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aUV);
    
    gl.clearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0,6);
   }
   
   // Runs when the page is refreshed/closed
   onunload = function() {
    gl.deleteProgram(program);
    gl.deleteBuffer(buffer);
    gl.deleteTexture(texture);
    gl = null;
   }
  
  }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried renamin it in jsbin but it didnt worked out.check here https://jsbin.com/peyoqaz/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thanyou so much